# How efficient am I using these tables in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

So I've been scripting some Lua and when using tables I wanted to make something similar to a "node" or "class"

```
local playerInfo = {} 
if player then
    local newPlayer = {NAME = name, HP = 10, DMG = 4}
    table.insert(playerInfo, newPlayer) 
end

for k, v in pairs(playerInfo) do
    print(v.NAME) 
end
```

This is just an example of what I'm doing, but is it OK to access information like this? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: In this example, it's preferred to use `ipairs` over `pairs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When talking about efficiency one has to differ between code maintenance and performance. In Lua, like in most languages, these two points go apart.

It's easy always to use `pairs` instead of `ipairs`, append elements to table by `table.insert`, concatenate strings by `..`, etc. **BUT** that's not the way for a fast running program.

One document every Lua programmer should have read: [Lua Performance Tips by Roberto Ierusalimschy](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf)

To your code:

- Don't use `table.insert`, manage table size & insertions by yourself.
- Your table has just array entries, so use `ipairs` instead.
- Avoid useless variables, construct in-place as far as possible (`newPlayer`).
- Use `_` as placeholder for unused variable names (`k`).

For [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/luajit.html) there're some other rules because of massive optimizations by the compiler part, f.e. `(i)pairs` is there much less a slow-down.

Comment: Thanks for the input. 

When you say 'useless' variables, you mean to just do something like `table.insert(playerInfo, {NAME = name, HP = 10, DMG = 4})`  instead?

I will remember to use `_` as well. There are some loops where I actually use `k` but that makes sense.  

and for `table.insert` how would I manage the size insertion myself if I don't know how many entries into the table I'm going to get?

Comment: @krazyito65 Yes, i meant that about 'useless' variables. `table.insert` asks for table size which hasn't cost of O(1) (see [implementation](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua/blob/master/src/ltable.c#L560)). Additionally tables can have holes by nil values and table size request considers these holes as end. Storing the table size as field **n** and increment/decrement it by modifications is more work for users but is safer and faster.

Comment: Using _ for unused variables is a readability-enhancing convention (and code inspection warning inhibitor).  In Lua, the only performance gain would be if you used it repeatedly. It's just like any other variable.